# Is there an example domain which is guaranteed not to exist?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I would like to use a domain name in an example. I know that `example.com` exists for this purpose, but I would like the domain name not to exist (and not to start existing later). **Is there any canonical example of a domain name which is guaranteed not to exist?**

Answer (score 39):

As per [RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761) section 6.4, the domain `invalid.` and any names falling within `.invalid.`, can be assumed not to exist.

Comment: I wonder what the RFC means by "names falling within .invalid."  -- host www.invalid.com has address 173.0.129.46 (so what, exactly is the *legal* hostname that is guaranteed never to resolve? cuz .invalid. is not a legal hostname...)

Comment: I think this means "hostnames ending with .invalid", I guess the extra dot at the end is just a notation.

Comment: The `.` at the end refers to the root zone, the one to which all top-level domains belong. It does not mean "substring contained", it means that when normalized to a FQDN ("fully qualified domain name", which implies having the root zone dot at the end), it does not end with `.invalid.`